# Python solve discretized pde with boundary conditions

Tags: python, differential-equations, pde

I have two functions (f,g) defined on a discrete unidimensional grid that come from the discretization of a pde:

and I would like to solve them given initial conditions X0, Y0 and periodic boundary conditions

```
x[0] = x[-1]
y[0] = y[-1]
```

How can I do this by using a python package as scipy.integrate or similar? I have already implemented a RK scheme but I guess it is very slow and offers low degree flexibility.

Comment: If you have already an RK scheme, then you have a block or function that realizes `k1=f(t,ut)`. Isolate this as a function to pass to the scipy ODE solvers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, could you tell me more in detail how with the package?